# how facebook handled onclick of desktop notification ,even if my facebook tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I am developing desktop based notification using Mozilla notification API. I have developed desktop notification which perform same functionality as Gmail , but I want  to handle one case that is, when my tab is closed then how to handle notification. Facebook has handled it very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to send push notifications while the website is not open in any tab, then you must implement a [service worker (mdn link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to handle push notifications. Your website can register this worker when the user visits, and then when the user closes your site, the worker can still run as long as the browser process is running. Then your server can communicate with the service worker with some data, and your service worker can use that data to show a push notification or whatever browser logic you want it to run at that point (however, it doesn't have access to the DOM).